# Is there a way to write a power-shell script which loop through all the lists inside our sub-sites and hide certain column/s from the list views

Tags: 2013, workflow, development, powershell

I am working on a team site collection inside my sharepoint enterprise 2013. and i have defined a global workflow linked to one of our custom site content types. now i am facing a problem is that whenever i create a new list which uses the custom content type, then the global workflow will show a status field as follow when an new item is created:-

[image]

now i search for a solution for this issue, such as setting the workflow to not create such a list column, but seems this can not be achieved as there is not such a setting inside the workflow.

now i am asking if i can implement such as workaround:-

1. create a power-shell script and schedule it to run let say each 30 minutes using windows scheduler tool.
2. the power-shell script will loop through all the current sub-sites inside the site collection.
3. then for each sub-site to loop through its lists.
4. and for each list to hide the list column (named AssingItemNumber in my case) if it is presented.

so in this case whenever i create a new list , and I add a new item, then the workflow status column will be shown ,, and after 30 minutes or less it will be removed by the power-shell script.

so can anyone adivce on this appraoch please?

Comment: please try this link https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/valdon/2009/05/05/removing-extra-workflow-status-column-in-default-view/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code:

```
$SiteCollection = Get-SPsite "https://sitecollectionurl" 

foreach($Site in $SiteCollection)
{
    #Loop through all Sub Sites
   foreach($Web in $Site.AllWebs)
   {
     Write-Host $web.title ": " $web.URL         
     $spList = $web.Lists.TryGetList("List")
     if($spList -ne $null){
         $spView = $spList.DefaultView
         #check if defaultview contains the column
         if ($spView.ViewFields.SchemaXml.Contains("AssingItemNumber")){
             $spView.ViewFields.Delete("AssingItemNumber") #use internal column name
             $spView.Update()    
         }
     }
  }  
}
```

Comment: so what will be the exact implication of this script ? will it be exactly similar to un-checking the field by modifying the related list view using the UI ? in other words is running such a code on a schedule basis considered safe ?

Comment: Yes its similar to unchecking the list view using UI and its perfectly safe.